# Displaying a framebuffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I've been learning a bit of OpenGL lately, and I just got to the Framebuffers.

So by my current understanding, if you have a framebuffer of your own, and you want to draw the color buffer onto the window, you'll need to first draw a quad, and then wrap the texture over it? Is that right? Or is there something like `glDrawArrays(), glDrawElements()` version for framebuffers?

It seems a bit... Odd (clunky? Hackish?) to me that you have to wrap a texture over a quad in order to draw the framebuffer. This doesn't have to be done with the default framebuffer. Or is that done behind your back?

Comment: [This](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. The main point of framebuffer objects is to render scenes to buffers that will *not* get displayed but rather reused somewhere, as a source of data for some other operation (shadow maps, High dynamic range processing, reflections, portals...).

If you want to display it, why do you use a custom framebuffer in the first place?

Now, as @CoffeeandCode comments, there is indeed a [glBlitFramebuffer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml) call to allow transfering pixels from one framebuffer to another. But before you go ahead and use that call, ask yourself why you need that extra step. It's not a free operation...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I was under the impression that that might be how double/triple buffering was done (yes I realise now that drivers have more optimized implementations for that). No wonder I couldn't find anything on drawing them

Comment: Wait, so how is post processing done then? All the sites I've looked at suggests doing multiple rendering passes, and then put all the passes onto a quad as a texture

Comment: All the post processing is done to frame buffer objects, except the last one (though it is often worth trying to combine them in less passes if possible). Yes, they are done with either a quad or an oversized triangle.